# Entity Framework CF: cannot create foreign key constraint because of cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework

I'd like to create two tables where one table contains two columns referencing another and get some issues with it.
So, I have an Employee class in my model:

```
public class Employee
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EmployeeId")]
    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeRequest> EmployeeRequests { get; set; }
}
```

Each employee can create EmployeeRequest, so we have a navigation property for it. EmployeeRequest looks like this:

```
public class EmployeeRequest
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid ManagerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Manager { get; set; }

    public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Besides EmployeeId, EmployeeRequest also must have ManagerId. Manager is also an Employee and a mandatory field.
The migration code is the following:

```
public partial class employee_request : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.EmployeeRequest",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    ManagerId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    EmployeeId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Employee", t => t.EmployeeId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Employee", t => t.ManagerId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.ManagerId)
            .Index(t => t.EmployeeId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Employee",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.EmployeeRequest", "ManagerId", "dbo.Employee");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.EmployeeRequest", "EmployeeId", "dbo.Employee");
        DropIndex("dbo.EmployeeRequest", new[] { "EmployeeId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.EmployeeRequest", new[] { "ManagerId" });
        DropTable("dbo.Employee");
        DropTable("dbo.EmployeeRequest");
    }
}
```

But when trying to update the DB, I get the following error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_dbo.EmployeeRequest_dbo.Employee_ManagerId' on table
>   'EmployeeRequest' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify
>   ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN
>   KEY constraints. Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Can someone explain me how to configure the context so it works with such configuration?

Comment: You can't.  The error talks about `multiple cascade paths`, by which is means you have cascaded deletes from `Employee` to `EmployeeRequests` ***twice*** *(once through EmployeeID and once through ManagerID)*.  It simply won't let you do that.  You need to remove one of the cascade deletes, or significantly restructure your data to only need one path.  Please add another comment if you are willing to make a significant re-structure to the data and I'll post an alternative *(though it will likely feel less tidy to you)*.

Comment: Hey Mat, thanks for the quick answer. I think I'd prefer to remove both cascade deletes, but I just cannot figure out how to do this. Do you have an idea about this?

Comment: You have two lines like this : `.ForeignKey("dbo.Employee", t => t.EmployeeId, cascadeDelete: true)`.  Have you tried setting the last property to false?

Comment: Yes, and it obviously works:). I'm just not sure if it's correct to manually edit them, thought there should be a wey to configure everything via attributes or fluent api.

Comment: I'm not much use there I'm afraid, I'm a DB geek only, not done any 'real' dev work in years.

Comment: Ok, anyway thanks for your help:). Will see, maybe I'll find some solution and then will post it here.